# Function which refers to an object. Both are in an object. What does "this" mean?

Tags: javascript, function, object, this

Nope, the title is not an enigma.

I have :

```
obj = {
    NaNException:function(message=''){
        this.message=message;
    },
    input:{
        integer:function(a){
            var b = prompt(a);
            if (isNaN(parseInt(b, 10)))
                throw new this.NaNException();
            else
                return b;
        }
    }
}
```

so, in `NaNException:function(){ }`, `this` is expected to be `NaNException`, but in `integer`, it is expected to be `obj`... which interpretation is the good one? And what can I do with the wrong one to have the expected result ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: obj, so global `obj.message` is the same object as `this.message` in your scope

Comment: It's impossible to say which value `this` will have because the value depends on how the functions are called. The only thing we can say is that since the function is called `this.NaNException`, `this` inside `NaNException` will refer to whatever `this` refers to in `integer`.